# Laravel - Editing Microsoft Word Documents Stored on AWS S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I have a Laravel web application that stores some word documents on AWS S3 and I'd like to be able to edit these documents on the fly. Currently the only way that I know how to do this is to download the file, open it, edit it, save it, and the reupload and replace the document already on S3. This just seems a bit cumbersome and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I'd like to be able to open the word document (either through an online app or via the native MS Word app), edit it, and when I save it, it would automatically save to the S3 file. Any advice?